# Python - Read Tokens from a String

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am reading all tokens (operators, `int`, `str`,  etc.) from a string

My current code:

```
import re
expression = "($mat.name == 'sign') AND ($most == 100.0)"
tokens = re.findall("\$+[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+|Not|not|NOT|[=]+|[+/*()-]|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+", expression)
```

The current result:

```
['(', '$mat.name', '==', 'sign', ')', 'AND', '(', 'most', '==', '100.0', ')']
```

The problem is that, while the regex is correctly matching `$mat.name`, it matches `most` instead of `$most`.

Can you please help me fix the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you're matching `most` instead of `$most` because it doesn't contain a dot and your expression is saying match either `\$+[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]+` or `[a-zA-Z]+` and obviously the `$most` string doesn't contain a `.` so it's trying the next match.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/q37ydT/3)

```
\$*(?:[a-z]*\.)?[a-z]+|not|[+/*()-]|\d*\.\d+|[\d=]+
```

**Note**: The above regex simplifies the original regex and is to be used with the `i` flag (ignore case)

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/TGKjis)

```
import re
expression = "($mat.name == 'sign') AND ($most == 100.0)"
tokens = re.findall(r"\$*(?:[a-z]*\.)?[a-z]+|not|[+/*()-]|\d*\.\d+|[\d=]+", expression, re.I)

print tokens
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
($mat.name == 'sign') AND ($most == 100.0)
```

#### Output

```
['(', '$mat.name', '==', 'sign', ')', 'AND', '(', '$most', '==', '100.0', ')']
```

---

### Explanation

I made some other changes to your pattern, so I'll explain the whole thing.

- Match any of the following

  - `\$+(?:[a-z]*\.)?[a-z]+` Match the following

    - `\$*` Match `$` literally any number of times
    - `(?:[a-z]*\.)?` Match the following zero or one time

      - `[a-z]*` Match any number of lowercase ASCII letters
      - `\.` Match a literal dot character `.`
    - `[a-z]+` Match one or more lowercase ASCII letters
  - `not` Match this literally
  - `[+/*()-]` Match any character in the set
  - `\d*\.\d+` Match the following

    - `\d*` Match any number of digits
    - `\.` Match a literal dot character `.`
    - `\d+` Match one or more digits
  - `[\d=]+` Match any character in the set (digits or `=`) one or more times

Comment: "" but you're matching most instead of $most  "" ,  Yes this was the problem ,  thanks for explanation, given regex is simpler than mine,

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following modified regex instead.

```
import re
expression = "($mat.name == 'sign') AND ($most == 100.0)"
tokens = re.findall("\$+[a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]+|\$+[a-zA-Z]*|[a-zA-Z]+|Not|not|NOT|[=]+|[+/*()-]|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+", expression)
print(tokens)
```

Which will print

```
['(', '$mat.name', '==', 'sign', ')', 'AND', '(', '$most', '==', '100.0', ')']
```

See a full explanation of the modified regular expression [here](https://regexr.com/3ic8q).

Answer (score -1):

In your second token, you got to check is `.` is present or not as `.` isn't mandatory in every variable as such!

```
>>> re.findall("\$+[a-zA-Z]*\.?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+|Not|not|NOT|[=]+|[+/*()-]|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+", expression)
['(', '$mat.name', '==', 'sign', ')', 'AND', '(', '$most', '==', '100.0', ')']
```

a similar solution goes as follows(simplifying the regex in question) -

```
>>> re.findall('\$+[A-Z.a-z]+|[a-zA-Z]+|Not|not|NOT|=+|[+/*()-]|[0-9.]+', expression)
['(', '$mat.name', '==', 'sign', ')', 'AND', '(', '$most', '==', '100.0', ')']
```